# Android launch screen

Tags: java, android, android-intent, splash-screen

I am building an Android application that opens different activities on start depending on firebase value. Right now I have an activity with just my logo that determines which activity to go to in its `onCreate` method. The problem is that I still get a white screen for half a second when launching my app because of the cold start. Is there a way to create a launch screen with my logo that will open a corresponding activity depending on returned firebase value and will replace the default white screen? Kinda like what WhatsApp or Instagram are doing these days. I know I can change window background in the styles.xml, but that's not ideal as it changes background everywhere and there will still be no way to determine which activity to open right on start

Comment: you have given your answer. Just modify a bit, use different theme styles in splash and other activities.

Comment: post your firebase database node structure and java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not change the background of all the windows. In order to show the splash screen instantaneously, consider using a custom theme just for the splash screen activity. Something like this:

**Styles.xml**

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_drawable</item>
</style>
```

**Splash Activity Screen layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/splashLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/splash_activity_progress"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:indeterminate="true"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

This will give you a Splash screen with a drawable(app logo). The progress bar let the user know that there are some background operations in progress.

To query the firebase you should use AsyncTask/Coroutine/Executor so that the operation is performed in background thread & the UI thread is not blocked. This is important to avoid ANRs.

Considering the fact that there is a possibility of [AsyncTask getting deprecated](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/base/+/1156409/6/core/java/android/os/AsyncTask.java), I suggest you consider wither Kotlin coroutines/Java executors framework instead of AsyncTasks.

Comment: It doesn't do anything. I have white screen on start

Comment: Do you have the drawable defined?

Answer (score 0):

Build a Splash screen that contains your logo.
It is very important to make firebase server (or any server) calls in the background.
Recommend you use AsyncTask with CallBack.

**Base example:**

The call back class:

```
public interface CallBack_TaskCompleted {
    void taskIsCompleted(boolean success);
}
```

AsyncTask:

```
private static class DownloadDataAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    CallBack_TaskCompleted callBack_taskCompleted;
    String someData = "";


    public DownloadDataAsync(String someData, CallBack_TaskCompleted callBack_taskCompleted) {
        this.callBack_taskCompleted = callBack_taskCompleted;
        this.someData = someData;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // Some download staff
        if (callBack_taskCompleted != null)
            callBack_taskCompleted.taskIsCompleted();

        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        MyUtils.logd("TAG", "onPostExecute");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        MyUtils.logd("TAG", "onPreExecute");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        MyUtils.logd("TAG", "onProgressUpdate" + values[0]);
    }
}
```

In your activity:

```
DownloadDataAsync downloadDataAsync = new DownloadDataAsync("DATA", new CallBack_TaskCompleted() {
    @Override
    public void taskIsCompleted() {
        // go to another activity
    }
});
```